# Hi, i want to find the max of the following sum in the query below

Tags: mysql, oracle10g

```
 $test = "select s.student_id, s.lastname, sum(p.amount)as Total, count(s.student_id),
     e.VALIDATEDDATE from student s, enroll e, payment p
     where  s.student_id = e.student_id and s.student_id = p.student_id
     and e.VALIDATEDDATE is not null group by s.student_id, e.VALIDATEDDATE, s.lastname;"
```

`$resut`= i want display the highest sum as max

Comment: create a sqlfiddle and people will start loving this question

Comment: Well, they might when they figure out which RDBMS you think you're using

Answer (score 0):

You can give it try with something like this

```
select s.student_id, s.lastname, sum(p.amount)as Total, count(s.student_id),
 e.VALIDATEDDATE from student s, enroll e, payment p
 where  s.student_id = e.student_id and s.student_id = p.student_id
 and e.VALIDATEDDATE is not null group by s.student_id, e.VALIDATEDDATE, s.lastname  ORDER BY sum(p.amount) desc
```

Comment: yes it looks fine, but how do i display the first value only. I mean the 3rd row.

Comment: OK use this 


select top 1 s.student_id, s.lastname, sum(p.amount)as Total, count(s.student_id),
 e.VALIDATEDDATE from student s, enroll e, payment p
 where  s.student_id = e.student_id and s.student_id = p.student_id
 and e.VALIDATEDDATE is not null group by s.student_id, e.VALIDATEDDATE, s.lastname  ORDER BY sum(p.amount) desc

Comment: i got this one: select max(Total) from  
(
select s.student_id, s.firstname, s.LASTNAME, sum(p.amount) as Total, count(s.student_id), e.VALIDATEDDATE from student s, enroll e, payment p where  s.student_id = e.student_id and s.student_id = p.student_id and e.VALIDATEDDATE is not null  group by s.student_id, e.VALIDATEDDATE , s.firstname, s.LASTNAME  ) a1 ;

Comment: do you mind to share any screen shot of result i guess you need some thing do with row number

Comment: Do you mind to share any screen shot of result i guess you need some thing do with row number may be this can HELP
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.student_id) AS RowID
 ,s.student_id, s.lastname, sum(p.amount)as Total, count(s.student_id),
 e.VALIDATEDDATE from student s, enroll e, payment p
 
 where  s.student_id = e.student_id and s.student_id = p.student_id
 and e.VALIDATEDDATE is not null group by s.student_id, e.VALIDATEDDATE, s.lastname  ORDER BY sum(p.amount) DESC
 ) AS StudenTable
 WHERE RowID=3

Comment: Thank you Muhammad Saqib, but the select is much eaiser using max(). MAX(TOTAL)                                                                                                              125000